# Jquery- how to write an onclick event using underscore js

Tags: jquery, underscore.js-templating

I have an underscore template that I'm trying to add a onclick event to a span element.The  `openQueryWindow()` is a function and im trying to pass individual parameters

`('<%?stat= sqlcreate%>')`as they execute different sql queries.Below is the template:

```
<dt class="create">Create:</dt><dd class="value">'
  +'<span class="create"onclick = "openQueryWindow('<%?stat= sqlcreate%>')"></span></dd>'
+'<dt class="delete">Delete:</dt><dd class="value">'
  +'<span class="delete"onclick = "openQueryWindow('<%?stat= sqldelete%>')"></span></dd>'  
+'<dt class="stop">Stop:</dt><dd class="value">'
  +'<span class="stop"onclick = "openQueryWindow('<%?stat= sqlstop%>')"></span></dd>'.
```

This is not quite work, what im in doing wrong? any ideas?

EDIT:
below is the jsp openQueryWindow():

```
function openQueryWindow(extra) {

        <c:if test="${!actionBean.parentLoadTest}">
        if (allowQueries()) {
            var url = "/load/query/${actionBean.loadTest.id}";
            if (extra) {
                url += extra;
            }

            window.open(url);
        } else {
            notifyQueryNotAvailable();
        }
        </c:if>
    }
```

Comment: Is there any reason your js needs to be included as inline html? It would be cleaner to append it in a separate js file.

Comment: What are you expecting `<%?stat= sqlcreate%>` to produce? And aren't getting your quotes messed up?

Comment: no, not really, the js does not necessarily have to be inline, but im not sure how can i append all 3 values using the openQueryWindow()

Comment: What's wrong with `$('.create').click(function() { openQueryWindow('?stat=sqlcreate') })`?